# Is determinePrimaryKeyJoinColumnName() ever used in Hibernate 5 ImplicitNamingStrategy?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on hibernate 5 and implemented the ImplicitNamingStrategy interface. Among other methods, there are two methods called determinePrimaryKeyJoinColumnName(...) and determineJoinColumnName(...). In the java doc, it says about determinePrimaryKeyJoinColumnName:

> Determine the column name related to {@link javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn}.  In
>        * {@code hbm.xml} terms, this would be a {@code } defined for a {@code }
>        * or a {@code } (others?)

I annotated my joins with PrimaryKeyJoinColumn and the code works, however the names never get routed through determinePrimaryKeyJoinColumnName(...) but through determineJoinColumnName(...).

Am I wrong in believing this is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` can be used like `@JoinColumn` only for the `@OneToOne` mapping. In such situation an additional join column is not used and, of course, the name of such "not existing column" is not generated.

`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` can be used for an inheritance too. For an example

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "someDiscriminator")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long customerPid;

    @Column
    private String customerName;

}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "xxxYY")
public class ValuedCustomer extends Customer {

    @Column
    private String valuedCustomerName;

}
```

Hibernate will use `xxxYY` for a column name. But if you do not specify a name

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public class ValuedCustomer extends Customer {

    @Column
    private String valuedCustomerName;

    }

}
```

Hibernate will not use `determinePrimaryKeyJoinColumnName()` to generate a name. So, looks like, it is a bug.

Hibernate calls `determinePrimaryKeyJoinColumnName()` only in one place [Ejb3JoinColumn.java#L719](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/2b66cd72bbcf96a07820e7c2f7ee61c23819f8c5/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/Ejb3JoinColumn.java#L719). But I can't get in which situations this happens.

I have encountered such problems too, when try to implement an adapter of Hibernate 4 `NamingStrategy` for Hibernate 5. You can refer [ImprovedNamingStrategy for Hibernate 5](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/README.md#improvednamingstrategy-for-hibernate-5) for an additional notes.

And my try to implement [Hibernate 5 Implicit Naming Strategy](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/README.md#hibernate-5-implicit-naming-strategy).